# How to Add Background Images in 2.8 and later

Tags: image

2.81a here. I am trying to add a "background image" similar to how [2.7x-based this tutorial shows](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-background-image-simply-explained/#adding-images), so that I see a screen that looks *something* like this:

[image]

However I can't figure out how/where to access this screen in 2.81a as the UI is wildly different. **Any ideas?**

I am new to Blender so if you can provide a click-by-click list of instructions it would be enormously appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Blender 2.81 by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then going to *Image* > *Reference.* In all honesty, it doesn't matter whether you choose reference or background. The added image will be directly facing the viewport camera at the time of adding it, so align your viewport to the correct orientation you want the image to first.

When you select the image, you will have an *Object Data Properties* tab with a picture icon on the right side menu. Click on it and you can now change the settings for the image.
[image: Object Data Properties Menu]

If you check *Use Alpha* and change the Transparency bar, you can change the transparency of the object. Changing *Depth* will cause the image to be displayed in front of or behind your objects. Changing *Side* will allow you to see it only from the front/back, useful if you have both front and back reference photos.

The *Display Orthographic* and *Display Perspective* checkboxes allow you to decide if you want to be able to see the reference in the respective view modes.

You might find that being able to select your reference image while editing is annoying. In the top right corner, click on the *Filter* button, and under *Restriction Toggles*, enable the *Selectable* option (its an icon of a cursor). Now, just disable the *Selectable* icon next to the reference image and you can no longer select it.

[image: Filters]